Reason for Second Authentication Phase in Bluetooth Secure Pairing
In bluetooth secure pairing: numeric comparison and paskey entry
(Bluetooth Pairing Description)
there are two authentication phases. I understand the reason for the first authentication phase: to prevent man in the middle attack using human interaction as a trusted channel.
However I am not sure in what cases authentication phase 2 help. The most attacks that I know (a paper describing many attacks), if they bypass authentication phase 1, they also bypass authentication phase 2.
Any thoughts/ideas/cases when authentication phase 2 comes useful?

This would probably be a better fit for Security.SE

That being said, it’s not clear what specifically you’re referencing in the context of the page you linked, since at first glance it describes only a single step at which authentication happens in Phase 2. Unless I’m missing something or misinterpreting, there is nothing in the way of authentication happening in what the linked article describes as “Phase 1”.

The correct sequence (as outlined in the article) involves three pairing phases, with only Phase 2 being used for authentication. Here's a quick summary:
Phase 1: Pairing feature exchange
This phase serves as a setup or pre-pairing stage, during which the two devices exchange their capabilities. For example, if a phone is pairing with a laptop, both devices share information such as having a keyboard AND a display. This process is known as IO Capabilities exchange. Additional features are also exchanged, such as support for Out of Band (OOB) pairing, Secure Connections, etc.
Phase 2: Key generation method and authentication
This is the critical phase where authentication occurs, and MITM (Man-in-the-Middle) attacks are mitigated (if requested during Phase 1). In this phase, the devices verify each other’s identity, often by displaying a shared confirmation code (e.g. 1234) that both parties must match. For instance, in the phone and laptop example, both devices would display the same code, and both have to confirm that the code matches.
Phase 3: Key generation and exchange
Here, the devices generate and exchange encryption keys. These keys are unique to the pairing devices and are then used to encrypt the Bluetooth packets that are exchanged between the two devices, ensuring that only the paired devices can decrypt them. Even if a malicious actor intercepts the data, they cannot decrypt the packets without the generated keys.
In summary, you're correct that if an attacker manages to initiate a pairing process and successfully passes Phase 1 (feature exchange), they are usually stopped at Phase 2 (key method selection and authentication), where identity verification occurs. If an attacker somehow bypasses this phase, they could potentially tamper with the connection. However, additional safeguards, such as Out of Band (OOB) pairing, require proximity or other specific conditions to ensure secure and legitimate pairing, further mitigating such risks.

"if an attacker manages to initiate a pairing process and successfully passes Phase 1 (feature exchange), they are usually stopped at Phase 2 (key method selection and authentication), where identity verification occurs." Can you give an example when does this occur?
